# Adding a chunk of WordprocessingML to word document

Tags: .net, ms-office, openxml, office-2010

Is it possible to add a 'chunk' of WordprocessingML to a word document (as opposed to a whole document)?  I currently have a docx that I use as my template, this contains a ContentControl.  I want to insert a section of WordprocessingML via an AltChunk but the content I insert is rendered as text, rather than being implemented into the document as I was hoping.

The method I'm currently using is:

```
var main = doc.MainDocumentPart;

// Create new AltChunk
string altChunkId = "altChunkId";
AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = main.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);

// Populate altChunk. stream = MemoryStream containing WordprocessingML
chunk.Feed(stream);

// Replace content control with altChunk info
AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

// Get SdtBlock to replace
SdtBlock block = ContentControlHelpers.GetSdtBlock(doc, "ContentControlId");
OpenXmlElement parent = block.Parent;
parent.InsertAfter(altChunk, block);
block.Remove();
```

A sample of the WordproccessingML that I'm trying to insert is this (generated via XML + XSLT.):

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="heading2" />
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Product 1</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="heading3" />
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Europe</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="heading4" />
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>France</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

I've tried adding the `<w:document>` and `<w:body>` elements round this to wrap it but whatever I'm trying the document is just rendering the WordprocessingML as text, as it is displayed above, rather than embedding it into the document.

Any suggestions as to where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at DocumentBuilder - Open Source example and guidance that shows how to do exactly what you want.

http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/documentbuilder.aspx

Watch the following video first:

http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/08/17/new-screen-cast-short-and-sweet-intro-to-documentbuilder-2-0.aspx

-Eric

Comment: Thanks Eric, this looks promising however I receive the error "Not an Open XML document." when using DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(). Is this because my snippet isn't a full wml document? Anyway round this?